# How to actually search all files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, full-text-search

I am using Visual Studio.  Say for instance I have a static public method named `FooBar()` in class Utils. Let's also say that I use this method in a lot of `.aspx` files.  Let's say I change the method signature of `FooBar()` to `FooBar(string)`, and subsequently I'd like to find all the instances of `Utils.FooBar` so I can update them.

Now let's say I go to the Solution Explorer search box, select "Search within file contents", and type `Utils`.  Despite the fact that I make `Utils.*` method calls everywhere, the only thing that shows up is the `Utils.cs` file.  If I keep typing `Utils.FooBar`, nothing shows up.

Right now, I am launching a Cygwin window and using grep since normal windows search is pretty useless too.  But it seems like there there must be an actual way of searching within all files in Visual Studio. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

I think you are talking about <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, by default it should be on "look in: entire solution" and there you go.

Comment: It would be nice if this came with a insta-preview window like CTRL + , (go to all)

Comment: This is a welcome coincidence for a long-time Intellij IDEA user.

Comment: exactly the magic I was looking for.

Answer (score 40):

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

Then you will see a docked window under name of "Go to all"

This a picture of the "Go to all" in my IDE

[image: Picture]

Comment: But it cannot find text (I'm not talking about symbols) within project/solution. At least in VS 2017 (v15.6.5)

Comment: The go to all with search within file contents would be ideal.

Comment: It only lists top results not all results.

Answer (score 37):

So the answer seems to be to NOT use the Solution Explorer search box.

Rather, open any file in the solution, then use the control-f search pop-up to search all files by:

1. selecting "Find All" from the "--> Find Next / <-- Find Previous" selector
2. selecting "Current Project" or "Entire Solution" from the selector that normally says just "Current Document".

Comment: the issue is that sometimes i dont have the option "Entire Solution" but i dont know why yet. The `ctrl + shift + f` approach works.

Answer (score 16):

One can access the "**Find in Files**" window via the drop-down menu selection and search all files in the **Entire Solution**:
Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files

[image]

Other, alternative is to open the "**Find in Files**" window via the "**Standard Toolbars**" button as highlighted in the below screen-short:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Preface:** As others have said, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is the tool, but I am so often frustrated by the fact that the default options don't find *everything!*

**Answer:** If you want to search *every* file then, from the "Find in Files" tab:

1. Click the ellipses to the right of "Look in" then choose the folder containing your Solution.
2. Set "File types" to `*`
3. Click "Find All" and *finally* find what you were looking for.

*Warning*: The search could take a while and it may find occurrences in files that shouldn't be edited.

[image: Search all files in the Solution.]

Comment: Wish I'd seen this before having to rediscover for myself! The default search filetype in VS 2019 includes this pattern: **`*\.*`**  - which doesn't really match all files and should be replaced by **`*`** or **`*.*`**

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2022 has come up with a very powerful search feature. I have used this feature in VS 2022 17.5.

In my case I just double-clicked the method name and pressed ctrl + t. and you see the magic.

[image]

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/new-better-search-in-visual-studio/