# How can I search for a string of JavaScript code in a large project?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I am new to a company and their code is not documented. I'm calling a complex function but cannot get it to work. I'd like to see how this function is called in their production code. The more examples of it's usage I can find, the better. This function is rarely called. All of their code exists in one Visual Studio project. There is about 150 sub-projects. I'd say the chance that a sub-project uses this function is 5%. Each project contains a wide variety of file types. What I'd like to do specifically, if find all JavaScript files with "insert string here" in their code. How can I do this?

This project is also hosted by Team Foundation Server.

Comment: notepad++ has a good "Find in Files" option.

Comment: Thanks Simon I'm trying it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310572/how-to-actually-search-all-files-in-visual-studio

Comment: I've have to search each solution. As stated, there are 150 solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notepad++ has a great find-in-file tool. However, it took a long time because it had to search through 2.43GB of data. You can see how to use it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLGV_iMOGsY

Thank you for the suggestion Simon! It found 66 results.