# How to resolve Python Package DeprecationWarning

Tags: python, ray, deprecation-warning, rllib

I received the following error message in Microsoft Visual Studio using the Ray RLlib package in python (Scalable Reinforcement Learning).

**`ray.rllib.agents.callbacks` has been deprecated. Use `ray.rllib.algorithms.callbacks` instead.**

Are there any guidelines on how to do this properly?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using `ray.rllib.agents.callbacks` in your own code, or is this due to another library using it? If it's in another library, try updating that library.

Comment: @Barmar It's in another library. Do you know how I can do a global search in visual studio? Instead of stepping through each script?

Comment: [How to search all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310572/how-to-actually-search-all-files-in-visual-studio)